# Using connector c++ to access MYSQL database (How to add a path to my standard search directory)

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, search-path

I am relatively new to programming&C++ and just began learning about MYSQL. I have been searching for a couple of days but couldn't find a solution. I usually use Cygwin&VIM&g++ to write, compile and run codes that I write.

My goal is to retrieve data from MYSQL database that I've set up on my laptop and be able to run a simple algorithm on that data and possibly update the database.

I went into MYSQL's website and went through tutorials and found an example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html). I have Boost, Connector, MYSQL server lib downloaded. When I run it, I get an error saying 'connection.h' was not found. I'm sure this is because when I compile it, g++ does not have the location of the library added to the search path that it goes through. The example has something like:

> `#include <cppconn/conneciton.h>`

where these angled brackets means it is going to search (after the current directory) the standard search directory. I am guessing I have to add a new path (the location of where the libraries are) so that the compiler looks at that standard directory and compiles the header.

Through googling I am thinking in g++ I can use -L*dir* -I to add a new search path but I don't get how to use it. Can anyone kindly explain/show me (by example) how to get over with this problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An #include issue would be solved with -I (-L is for a library if it is needed but first you have to get through the compile).

You need to figure out where the headers were installed (likely somewhere under either /usr/include or /usr/local/include/), and then add a -I with that directory, it may also be that you need to install a development package, many *nix distributions split based on runtime-build time distinctions.

And note also with the -I that the package may do something like install to /usr/include/libraryname/libname_version/libname in such a case you would only want to add -I/usr/include/libraryname/libname_version/ and then in your source file have #include